# .desktop that copies clicked urls to clipboard in place of a default browser

Tags: bash, kubuntu, kde, .desktop, xclip

I would like to create a simple .desktop file that I can use in place of a default browser that simply copies any clicked url to the clipboard and displays a short confirming message. I have written this desktop entry but am having some problems with it...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=urltoclip
Exec=bash -c 'echo %U | xclip -selection c; echo copied url to clipboard!; $SHELL'
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=browser
```

The .desktop runs from explorer (though without any input to %U doesn't copy anything) but when I set it as the default browser in the system settings and click a link I get the following error:

> Unknown error code 100 execvp: Exec format error Please send a full bug report at https://bugs.kde.org

[image: Unknown error code 100 execvp: Exec format error Please send a full bug report at https://bugs.kde.org]

I am running kde plasma (within ubuntu-studio) and setting the default browser in the system settings here:

[image: kde plasma system settings showing the applications tab > default applications > web browser set as a custom .desktop file]

Anyone have an idea as to what might be the issue here? Thank you for any help.

Comment: The file with extension .desctop is not a program or an executable script. It is a shortcut that needs to be clicked. When you set it as the default browser, it does not run as on one clicks it. Try entering the `mycode.desktp` or whatever you called it in the terminal as a command and see what happens.

Comment: Ah I see, so I should be using a shell script? 
I'm not sure how to pass the url from the clicked link to a script when it is set as the default browser (in the same way you would do with '%U' in a .desktop's Exec parameter)

Comment: I have no idea.